# Ray-tune log results in two folders

Tags: python, logging, hyperparameters, ray

I using ray-tune to fine-tune parameter.

Based on the docs, ray-tune log the results of each trial to a sub-folder under a specified local dir, which defaults to `~/ray_results`.

To change *ray_results* to a *custom folder*, I used the following:

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")

experiment_name = f"doc2vec-experiemt_{timestamp}"
tuner = tune.Tuner(
    tune.with_resources(train_model, {"cpu":4}),
    param_space=search_space,
    run_config=air.RunConfig(storage_path="my_custom_folder_results/",
                              name=experiment_name),
    tune_config=tune.TuneConfig(num_samples=20),
    )
```

I figure out that ray-tune log results in both folder, the default one: `~/ray_results` and `my_custom_folder_results/`